# Running only one instance of an application,(Quit new instance and Display old instance or give Focus)

Tags: c#, winforms

My app has a default setting that makes it run on the Icon tray when you boot your computer.
If you click on the Icon from the Icon tray then the app is displayed on the desktop window.
Further more if a user try to launch a new instance of my app whilst the old one is running, I just display a message that another instance is running and then Quit the new instance.

Now I want the New instance not only to quit but also makes the Old instance active/displayed on the desktop.
This is my present code

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(
           System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(kingCobra.Properties.Resources.Msg_Multiple_Starts, 
                    kingCobra.Properties.Resources.Multiple_Starts,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally Got what I wanted from [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/C-Single-Instance-App-With-the-Ability-To-Restore). My main problem was to bring the old instance from the Icon tray whilst closing the new

```
 static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!SingleInstance.Start()) {
            SingleInstance.ShowFirstInstance();
            return;
        }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    try {
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

    SingleInstance.Stop();
}
} 
//And secondly within your main form, the following code must be added:

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    if (message.Msg == SingleInstance.WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE) {
        Show

Window();
    }
    base.WndProc(ref message);
} 

public void ShowWindow()
{
    // Insert code here to make your form show itself.
    WinApi.ShowToFront(this.Handle);
}
```

Comment: I pulled that code from CodeProject and plugged it in nearly verbatim on a Winforms project that used the sys tray and it just worked.

Comment: happy to know that the link was useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to add this to your main class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Then you need to obtain a reference to the process that is already running, and then call the SetForegroundWindow method like this:

```
  SetForegroundWindow(SameProcess.MainWindowHandle);
```

You do not need to kill the current process like you are currently doing, just return after focusing the other process' main window as shown above

This is a full working example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName))
    {
        if (p.Id != currentProcess.Id)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already running");
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            return;
        }
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your method looks straight t forwad and nice: But unfortunately from the tests so far, I haven't been able to achieve what I want.
==> SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);//if window is in Normal state, bring window to top Most 
==> ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, WindowShowStyle.ShowNormal); //if window is in minimized or max state, make it topmost and Normal state
                                                                              ==> Both do not seem to work when program is in Tray

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way I've ever seen to get this job done.

```
public class SingleInstanceController : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    public SingleInstanceController()
    {
        IsSingleInstance = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Form1 form = MainForm as Form1;
        form.Text = "I will run only once!";
        form.Activate();

        base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
    }

    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        MainForm = new Form1();
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        SingleInstanceController controller = new SingleInstanceController();
        controller.Run(args);
    }
}
```

Actual code from this article [Single Instance Application](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Note: this requires you to add reference of *Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Threading Mutex and  user32.dll

try this

Step 1 :
Declare the following constantes:

```
private const int SW_NORMAL = 1; // see WinUser.h for definitions
private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPlacement")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

[DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "GetWindowPlacement")]
private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);


private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
}
```

Step 2 :
Add this methode :

```
public void application_run(Form form1)
{
bool createdNew;

            System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, form1.Name, out createdNew);
            if (!createdNew)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("...", "...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);//Alert message

                try
                {
                    // see if we can find the other app and Bring it to front
                    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, form1.Text);
                    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        LoaderDomain.WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new LoaderDomain.WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                        placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
                        GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref placement);
                        placement.showCmd = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
                        SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref placement);
                        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                    }
                }
                catch 
                {
                    //rien
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Application.Run(form1);
            }
            // keep the mutex reference alive until the normal termination of the program
            GC.KeepAlive(m);
```

}

Step 3 :
Replace in the main

```
Application.run(forms);
```

by a call to previous the methode

Comment: Using a mutex is ok, but identifying the other window by its Text property is dirty! What if the text changes runtime?

Comment: I read back the FindWindow function on msdn you can use a className in place of window title if you want